# System.Timers - how to pass a variable into the ElapsedEvent that changes through each "foreach" iteration

Tags: c#, api, timer, event-handling

I'll try to keep this as simple as possible.  Here's my method, just to start - and I understand the below code is incorrect - this is just what I have at the moment:

```
public static void GetActorsFromCastList(TmdbMovieCast cast)
{
    // use timers here
    List<Cast> liCast = cast.cast;

    Timer actorTimer = new Timer(1000);

    // put the below into a foreach loop to get a new personId each time???

    foreach (var i in liCast)
    {
        actorTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler((sender, e) => RunActorEvent(sender, e, i.id));
        actorTimer.Start();
    }
}

public static void RunActorEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e, int personId)
{
    // run a single API call here to get a Person (actor)
    _actors.Add(_api.GetPersonInfo(personId));
}
```

As you can see, I created a `System.Timer` that, as designed above, the idea is to call the `RunActorEvent` every second and pass in a different `PersonId` each time.  The end goal is to call the `RunActorEvent` one time each second, but each time pass in a new `PersonId`.  I already created the `ElapsedEventHandler` such that I added a third parameter `PersonId`.

That's where I'm at.  The dilemma I'm having is this just doesn't look correct.  I mean, I have a `foreach` loop that essentially creates a new ElapsedEventHander through each iteration, and I don't think this should be the design.

**QUESTION**: How do I create a `System.Timer` and a corresponding `ElapsedEventHandler` but pass in a **new** variable (`PersonId`) into `RunActorEvent` (the Event Handler) each time the `ElapsedEventHander` is called?

Comment: @sino That is absolutely wrong. This is very easily possible.

Comment: @ tnw: right, I thought the guy want to have event arg that contain PersonID

Comment: Out of curiosity. Whats the reason to use a timer here? Does the api you are calling has some kind of throttling you are trying not to run into?

Comment: @Ralf, exactly... the third party API that I'm hitting has a speed limit of 30 calls every 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the `List<Cast>` to your event, Have a class level index on list and increment that index each time in the event something like:

```
actorTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler((sender, e) => RunActorEvent(sender, e, liCast));
```

Then in method:

```
int index = 0; //class level index
public static void RunActorEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e, List<Cast> list)
{
    int personId = list.ElementAt(index++); //or list[index++]
    _actors.Add(_api.GetPersonInfo(personId));
}
```

Comment: That kind of makes sense... I will give this a shot.

Comment: `RunActorEvent` would only be called after the timer elapsed. That would be after 1 second.

Answer (score 1):

Just another way of writing it which, in my opinion, is a bit cleaner...

```
actorTimer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => RunActorEvent(sender, e, personId);
```

Unrelated to your question, but this line hurts:

```
List<Cast> liCast = cast.cast;
```

`cast.cast` just doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: So I'll rename it to something like movieCast.cast. :)

Comment: @MikeMarks That's not really addressing the issue though. It would be better if you had something like `movie.cast`. Why is there a `cast` object that resides *within* a `cast`? I'm just pointing out that your class design is a little broken.

Comment: This is actually a third party library that I'm using that's calling a third party API.  So, yeah, I can rename it to movie, but I want to stay consistent with the third party library I'm using, as unconventional as it is, unfortunately..

Comment: I know, it's not perfect, and I would have designed the classes differently.

Comment: @MikeMarks Ah, I totally misunderstood then. Good luck!